# outline package, how to change enumeration style?

Tags: macros, package-options

I'm working with the `outlines` package. I want to change the 2nd level enumeration style from small letters ( *a b c* ) to small roman letters ( *i),ii),iii)...* ). In other words, I want to exchange the 2nd and 3rd level enumeration styles. I tried reading the documentation of the package but I didn't quite understand if I have to write my own code or just apply what's suggested in the doc. I think it may involve
`\renewcommand{\outlineii}{style}` but what do I put in place of *style*, `roman`? I'd like this change to affect all 2nd-level items.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{outlines}

\begin{document}

\section{First section} 
\subsection{First subsec} 
\begin{outline}[enumerate]

\1 Calculate $ E_{th} $.
\2 Write $f= f_{electr} + f_{elast}$:
\2 Apply Euler-Lagrange method 
\2 Calc each ``piece'' of the 2nd degree diff eq
  \3 first this
  \3 then the double derivative  
\2 Simplify \dots

\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outlines` takes the styles from `enumerate` labels. You can change these with the help of `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{outlines}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsec}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]

\1 Calculate $ E_{th} $.
\2 Write $f= f_{electr} + f_{elast}$:
\2 Apply Euler-Lagrange method
\2 Calc each ``piece'' of the 2nd degree diff eq
  \3 first this
  \3 then the double derivative
\2 Simplify \dots

\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the asterisk after _roman_ for in `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\roman*)}`? I'm just curious... ;)

Comment: @WobbyWindows That is how they are defined by `enumitem` package..

Comment: There is a possibility to do without a package "enumitem". See the second page in the "outlines" manual: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines/outlines.pdf